# How to remove lines with nonsense format numbers?

Tags: bash, text-processing, gnuplot, fortran

I have the following data that I am processing to get the 1st and 5th column, convert the `D` format to `E` format and delete rows that have gibberish numbers such as `9.410-316`.

```
DEG =      1.500
     2.600D+01     0.000D+00     0.000D+00     0.000D+00     0.000D+00
     2.700D+01     8.720-304     2.369-316     7.556-316     9.410-316
     4.300D+01     1.208D-83     4.156D-96     7.360D-96     6.984D-96
     1.590D+02     8.002D-07     6.555D-19     7.748D-19     7.376D-19
     1.600D+02     1.173D-06     9.669D-19     1.143D-18     1.089D-18
     1.610D+02     1.709D-06     1.417D-18     1.676D-18     1.596D+01
     1.620D+02     2.468D-06     2.058D-18     2.436D-18     2.320D-10
DEG =     18.500 
     2.700D+01     2.794-314     0.000D+00     0.000D+00     0.000D+00
     2.800D+01     4.352-285     1.224-297     3.685-297     4.412-297
     8.800D+01     1.371D-02     6.564D-15     7.852D-15     7.275D-15
```

My problem is in identifying the number formats that I want to delete. So far, I have tried

```bash
maxa=18.5
maxangle=$(printf "%.3f" $maxa)
if (( $(echo "$maxa < 10" | bc -l) )); then
  txt2search="DEG =      $maxangle"
  # 6 spaces between = and value if deg=>10, else only 5)
else
  txt2search="DEG =     $maxangle"
fi

line=$(grep -n "$txt2search" file  | cut -d : -f 1)

# Once the line number is read for the string, skip a few lines (4) and read next several lines(1000)
beginline=$((line + 4))
endline=$((line + 1002))
awk -v a="$beginline" -v b="$endline" 'NR==a, NR==b {print $1, $5}' fileinput > fileoutput
sed -i 's/D/E/g' fileoutput
```

Then, to discard the rows with the nonsense numbers, I tried (one at a time) and failed with the following commands.

```bash
sed -ni '/E/p' fileoutput
sed -E '/(E)/!d' fileoutput > spec2.tempdata
sed '/E/!d' fileoutput > spec2.tempdata
awk '!/E/' fileoutput > spec2.tempdata
```

How can I identify and remove lines with such nonsense numbers? The versions are

- sed (GNU sed) 4.7
- grep (GNU grep) 3.4
- GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)

The output would be

```
2.600D+01     0.000D+00     0.000D+00     0.000D+00     0.000D+00
4.300D+01     1.208D-83     4.156D-96     7.360D-96     6.984D-96
1.590D+02     8.002D-07     6.555D-19     7.748D-19     7.376D-19
1.600D+02     1.173D-06     9.669D-19     1.143D-18     1.089D-18
1.610D+02     1.709D-06     1.417D-18     1.676D-18     1.596D+01
1.620D+02     2.468D-06     2.058D-18     2.436D-18     2.320D-10
```

**EDIT:** The solution that I was looking for is (see first comment)

```bash
grep -v '[0-9]-'
```

Comment: If all your "nonsense" numbers are like `x.y-z`, you can probably just use `grep -v '[0-9]-'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what exactly you consider "nonsense numbers" and show the expected output for your example input. Where do the magic numbes `4` and `1002` in your code come from? Are they related to your input?

Comment: As someone who deals with large amounts of numbers on the regular: I'm worried about the validity of your *whole* dataset if you got numbers in there that you can't interpret. These numbers just seem to be omitting the `D`, and would then be very close to the machine epsilon of double precision IEEE754 floating point numbers. That's a bit much of a coincidence. I don't believe in computers producing gibberish out of thin air – these numbers came into that dataset somehow, and you erasing a lot of very small numbers sounds like you're falsifying a statistic just because you're too lazy.

Comment: You claim "they cannot be interpreted as valid numbers", to which I say, "They can, you just have decided to not investigate them properly". I even offer you an (in humble opinion reasonable) interpretation: For numbers with an exponent < -99, the `D` is ommitted for space reasons!

Comment: Thanks @muru. Marcus, I know what I am doing, thanks for your inputs as well and I will leave it at that.

Comment: @csnl to be fair, that's fine by me – it's just that I saw way too many cases of data being prepared to exclude anything "hard" to handle, which led to systematic biases. If you know where these numbers come from – please accept my apologies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I think you meant well, so we are good.

Comment: Can you please explain why `9.410-316` cannot be interpreted as a valid number? I mean, 9.410-316=−306.59. Could we think of it another way, can we simply remove any entry if it has a `-` unless it is the first character or it follows a `D` or `E`?  And what should we do with the removed fields? Leave them blank? Add some filler? What is the expected output here?

Comment: A few questions on the script. You set `maxa` to a specific value but then but in a check to see what that value is. The checks are unnecessary. Your grep can also be simplified to `grep -En "DEG =\s+$maxangle"` so you don't have to count spaces.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maxa is a variable coming from another awk output. Numbers like 9.410-316 comes from an old Fortran code (over which I have no control) from an inadequate formatting/can-be-improved code. The – sign is not subtraction. I am not processing data with this script but collating data from various output files (from the same old code) for plotting  with gnuplot. I know why that number is so low/gibberish and I have sound reasons to ignore it, even if whatever I am doing it is for plotting purposes. Solution is what is given by @muru. Thanks for the all help.

Comment: Hi, you say you're "processing to get the 1st and 5th column" but you still show all five columns in your desired output? I can change my answer below if necessary. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW here's how to change the Ds to Es in your input and then tell if a field is a number or not by comparing it's value before and after adding `0` to it (a number will retain it's value, a non-number won't)

```
$ awk 'NF>3{gsub(/D/,"E"); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != $i+0) print "not a number:", $i}' file
not a number: 8.720-304
not a number: 2.369-316
not a number: 7.556-316
not a number: 9.410-316
not a number: 2.794-314
not a number: 4.352-285
not a number: 1.224-297
not a number: 3.685-297
not a number: 4.412-297
```

and so to print the lines that only contain numbers would be:

```
$ awk 'NF>3{gsub(/D/,"E"); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != $i+0) next; print}' file
     2.600E+01     0.000E+00     0.000E+00     0.000E+00     0.000E+00
     4.300E+01     1.208E-83     4.156E-96     7.360E-96     6.984E-96
     1.590E+02     8.002E-07     6.555E-19     7.748E-19     7.376E-19
     1.600E+02     1.173E-06     9.669E-19     1.143E-18     1.089E-18
     1.610E+02     1.709E-06     1.417E-18     1.676E-18     1.596E+01
     1.620E+02     2.468E-06     2.058E-18     2.436E-18     2.320E-10
     8.800E+01     1.371E-02     6.564E-15     7.852E-15     7.275E-15
```

or:

```
$ awk 'NF>3{gsub(/D/,"E"); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != $i+0) next} 1' file
DEG =      1.500
     2.600E+01     0.000E+00     0.000E+00     0.000E+00     0.000E+00
     4.300E+01     1.208E-83     4.156E-96     7.360E-96     6.984E-96
     1.590E+02     8.002E-07     6.555E-19     7.748E-19     7.376E-19
     1.600E+02     1.173E-06     9.669E-19     1.143E-18     1.089E-18
     1.610E+02     1.709E-06     1.417E-18     1.676E-18     1.596E+01
     1.620E+02     2.468E-06     2.058E-18     2.436E-18     2.320E-10
DEG =     18.500
     8.800E+01     1.371E-02     6.564E-15     7.852E-15     7.275E-15
```

depending on whether you want those `DEG` lines output or not.

Answer (score 4):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$  raku -e 'my @a; for lines.join("\n").split(/ \n <?before DEG> /) { @a.push: %(.split("\n").[0].words.[2] => \
             .split("\n")[1..*].map(*.words[0,4])>>.map(*.subst( / (\d+) (<[+-]>) /, {$0 ~ "e" ~ $1} ).subst(/D/, "e") )>>.Num) };  \
             .raku.put for @a;'  file
```

Sample Output for visualization purposes:

```perl
${"1.500" => $($(26e0, 0e0), $(27e0, 9.41e-316), $(43e0, 6.984e-96), $(159e0, 7.376e-19), $(160e0, 1.089e-18), $(161e0, 15.96e0), $(162e0, 2.32e-10))}
${"18.500" => $($(27e0, 0e0), $(28e0, 4.412e-297), $(88e0, 7.275e-15))}
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family that features rational numbers and Unicode support built-in. Above, the general strategy is to create an array-of-hashes, with the `DEG` value as `key` and measurements in columns 1 and 5 (index `[0,4]`) as `value`.

An `@`-sigiled array is declared (`@a`). The Raku code reads auto-chomped `lines` in, `join`ing them back together on `\n` newlines. From here we break into records by `split`ting on `\n` newlines that occur before `DEG`. Entering the `{ … }` block, each record is again `split` on `\n` newlines, with the `.[0].words.[2]` third-word-of-the-first element becoming a `key`. The `=>` fat-arrow denotes "pair" construction, with everything after becoming a `value`. Note the two `.subst` calls: the first to insert an "e" between a `\d` digit and a bespoke character-class consisting of `<[+-]>` plus-or-minus sign, and the second to change "D" to "e". Values are converted to `.Num`, and a `%( … )` hash is pushed onto the `@a` array. The `.raku` method is added to the output line to enable visualization of Raku's internal representation of the data (note `.perl` also works as a synonym).

---

---

***Actual Output for Plotting:***

Change the final line `.raku.put for @a` to get your desired output for plotting. A few examples below (alternatively you can use Raku's `printf` or `sprintf` if desired):

**1.** Replace out`put` line above to return the first `DEG`:

```perl
for @a[0].kv -> $k,$v {put ([Z] $k xx $v.elems, $v).join: "\n"}

#Returns 3-columns:

1.500 26 0
1.500 27 9.41e-316
1.500 43 6.984e-96
1.500 159 7.376e-19
1.500 160 1.089e-18
1.500 161 15.96
1.500 162 2.32e-10
```

**2.** Or return the whole 3-column table at once with the following out`put` line:

```perl
for @a { for ($_.kv) -> $k,$v {put ([Z] $k xx $v.elems, $v).join: "\n"}};

#Returns:

1.500 26 0
1.500 27 9.41e-316
1.500 43 6.984e-96
1.500 159 7.376e-19
1.500 160 1.089e-18
1.500 161 15.96
1.500 162 2.32e-10
18.500 27 0
18.500 28 4.412e-297
18.500 88 7.275e-15
```

**3.** ***FINALLY:***  Raku has a `=~=` "tolerance" operator which can be used to determine if values are approx. equal to zero (defaults to 1e-15, see link below). Putting it all together:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines.join("\n").split(/ \n <?before DEG> /) { @a.push: %(.split("\n").[0].words.[2] => \
            .split("\n")[1..*].map(*.words[0,4])>>.map(*.subst( / (\d+) (<[+-]>) /, {$0 ~ "e" ~ $1} ).subst(/D/, "e") )>>.Num) };  \
            for @a {  for ($_.kv) -> $k,$v {put ([Z] $k xx $v.elems,  $v>>.map( -> $i { ($i =~= 0) ?? 0 !! $i } )).join: "\n"}};'  file
1.500 26 0
1.500 27 0
1.500 43 0
1.500 159 0
1.500 160 0
1.500 161 15.96
1.500 162 2.32e-10
18.500 27 0
18.500 28 0
18.500 88 7.275e-15
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap.html
https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell.html#=%3E_Fat_comma
[https://docs.raku.org/routine/=~=.html](https://docs.raku.org/routine/=%7E=.html)
https://raku.org

Comment: Thanks @jubilatious1, this is an interesting alternative.

Comment: given the answer you accepted, raku can do that too ```raku -e 'for lines() { .grep( {! /\d"-"/} ) ?? .say !! next }' file```  ;-)

Comment: @p6steve nice one! Or maybe even: `~$ raku -ne '.put unless / \d \- /;' file` . But please don't take this comment as endorsing throwing out data--much better to use a tolerance criteria: https://docs.raku.org/routine/=~=.html

Comment: not sure why but I prefer talking about control flow for filtering `raku -pe 'next unless /^\d/;'`

Comment: i had forgotten the raku command flags -n and -p ... thanks for the reminder. just made a minor tweak to Matt's to get it to work on my data ```raku -pe 'next if / \d \- /' file``` https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell.html#Command-line_flags